# Proving a vector identity using Einstein summation

Tags: vectors, tensors

I need to prove
$$\nabla \times [(u\cdot \nabla)u]=(u\cdot \nabla)(\nabla \times u)-[(\nabla \times u)\cdot \nabla]u+(\nabla\cdot u)(\nabla \times u)$$

So the ith component of each side using Einstein summation convention is
$$LHS=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(u_m\partial_m)u_k$$ $$RHS=\epsilon_{ijk}u_m\partial_m\partial_ju_k-\epsilon_{jkl}\partial_ku_l\partial_ju_i+\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_mu_m\partial_ju_k$$
and I want to show that these two sides are equal. Ideally the LHS would expand into the RHS but I seem to be getting two terms rather than three (I think I'm misunderstanding how the product rule works when we have two differential operators) which I've written below $$LHS=\epsilon_{ijk}[(\partial_ju_m)(\partial_mu_k)+u_m\partial_j\partial_mu_k]$$
Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: The notation is a bit ambiguous - I have seen $u \cdot \nabla$ with the $\nabla$ used as a left acting as well as a right acting operator.

Comment: The way you expanded the left hand side is indeed valid.
I would place the second parenthesis at the very end of the line, though (in the second equation).
Where did you find that identity?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much I believe my answer or the given identity, but whatever I've done is too long for a comment so here's a (potentially partial) derivation.

We first use the identity $$(\mathbf u \boldsymbol \cdot \boldsymbol \nabla)\mathbf u = \underbrace{\frac 12 \boldsymbol \nabla(\mathbf u \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf u)}_{(1)} - \underbrace{\mathbf u \times (\boldsymbol \nabla \times \mathbf u)}_{(2)}.$$
When taking the curl, $(1)$  will vanish since the curl of a gradient is $\mathbf 0$. For $(2)$, \begin{align*}
&-\boldsymbol \nabla \times \Big[\mathbf u\times (\boldsymbol \nabla \times \mathbf u)\Big] \\
={}&-\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_i [\varepsilon_{jpq} u_p [\boldsymbol \nabla \times \mathbf u]_q]_j \mathbf e_k \\
={}& -\varepsilon_{jki} \partial_i \varepsilon_{jpq} u_p \varepsilon_{qmn} \partial_m u_n \mathbf e_k \\
={}& -(\delta_{kp}\delta_{iq} - \delta_{kq}\delta_{ip}) \varepsilon_{qmn} \partial_i u_p\partial_mu_n \mathbf e_k \\
={}& \varepsilon_{kmn} \partial_i u_i \partial_m u_n \mathbf e_k - \varepsilon_{imn} \partial_i u_k \partial_m u_n \mathbf e_k \\
={}& (\partial_iu_i) \left(\varepsilon_{kmn} \partial_mu_n \mathbf e_k\right) - \left[(\varepsilon_{imn} \partial_mu_n)\partial_i\right]u_k \mathbf e_k \\
={}& (\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf u)(\boldsymbol \nabla \times \mathbf u) - [(\boldsymbol \nabla \times \mathbf u) \boldsymbol \cdot \boldsymbol \nabla]\mathbf u.
\end{align*}
Whatever's going on with the other term I'm not sure! Trying to take the curl of $(1)$ hasn't been productive for me; and definitely hasn't got close to the required term $(\mathbf u \boldsymbol \cdot \boldsymbol \nabla)(\boldsymbol \nabla \times \mathbf u)$.

Comment: There is no need for tensor notation. Denote $\nabla \times u$ as $v$; then $\nabla \times (u \times v) = v \cdot \nabla u - (\nabla \cdot u)v + (\nabla \cdot v) u - u \cdot \nabla v$. The last term is $(u \cdot \nabla) (\nabla \times u$; the first term is $(\nabla \times u)\cdot \nabla u$; the second term is $(\nabla \cdot u) (\nabla \times u)$; the third term is $(\nabla\cdot(\nabla \times u))u=0$. Multiply by minus and you are done.